# Find and replace string values in list

Tags: python, string, list

I got this list:

```
words = ['how', 'much', 'is[br]', 'the', 'fish[br]', 'no', 'really']
```

What I would like is to replace `[br]` with some fantastic value similar to `<br />` and thus getting a new list:

```
words = ['how', 'much', 'is<br />', 'the', 'fish<br />', 'no', 'really']
```

Answer (score 368, accepted):

```
words = [w.replace('[br]', '<br />') for w in words]
```

This is called a [*list comprehension*](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 43):

You can use, for example:

```
words = [word.replace('[br]','<br />') for word in words]
```

Answer (score 40):

Besides list comprehension, you can try `map()`

```
>>> map(lambda x: str.replace(x, "[br]", "<br/>"), words)
['how', 'much', 'is<br/>', 'the', 'fish<br/>', 'no', 'really']
```

Or another way is `enumerate()` function

```
words = ['how', 'much', 'is[br]', 'the', 'fish[br]', 'no', 'really']

# Replacing items using enumerate()
for index, value in enumerate(words):
    # if value includes [br] then replace it with <br>
    if '[br]' in value:
        words[index] = value.replace('[br]', '<br>')

print(words)
# Output: ['how', 'much', 'is<br>', 'the', 'fish<br>', 'no', 'really']
```

`enumerate` is faster than `map`.

Answer (score 26):

In case you're wondering about the performance of the different approaches, here are some timings:

```
In [1]: words = [str(i) for i in range(10000)]

In [2]: %timeit replaced = [w.replace('1', '<1>') for w in words]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.98 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit replaced = map(lambda x: str.replace(x, '1', '<1>'), words)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.09 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit replaced = map(lambda x: x.replace('1', '<1>'), words)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.39 ms per loop

In [5]: import re

In [6]: r = re.compile('1')

In [7]: %timeit replaced = [r.sub('<1>', w) for w in words]
100 loops, best of 3: 6.15 ms per loop
```

as you can see for such simple patterns the accepted list comprehension is the fastest, but look at the following:

```
In [8]: %timeit replaced = [w.replace('1', '<1>').replace('324', '<324>').replace('567', '<567>') for w in words]
100 loops, best of 3: 8.25 ms per loop

In [9]: r = re.compile('(1|324|567)')

In [10]: %timeit replaced = [r.sub('<\1>', w) for w in words]
100 loops, best of 3: 7.87 ms per loop
```

This shows that for more complicated substitutions a pre-compiled reg-exp (as in `9-10`) can be (much) faster. It really depends on your problem and the shortest part of the reg-exp.

Answer (score 6):

An example with for loop (I prefer List Comprehensions).

```
a, b = '[br]', '<br />'
for i, v in enumerate(words):
    if a in v:
        words[i] = v.replace(a, b)
print(words)
# ['how', 'much', 'is<br/>', 'the', 'fish<br/>', 'no', 'really']
```

Comment: I found this example quite useful for a more complicated case where I couldn't sort out the list comprehension. Or more specifically, for a case where I didn't have time to sort out the list comprehension and then was able to later replace the code with comprehension when I got a chance.

Answer (score 3):

If performance is important, including an `if-else` clause improves performance (by about 5% for a list of 1mil strings, no negligible really).

```py
replaced = [w.replace('[br]','<br />') if '[br]' in w else w for w in words]
```

`map()` implementation can be improved by calling `replace` via `operator.methodcaller()` (by about 20%) but still slower than list comprehension (as of Python 3.9).

```py
from operator import methodcaller
list(map(methodcaller('replace', '[br]', '<br />'), words))
```

If it suffices to modify the strings in-place, a loop implementation may be the fastest.

```py
for i, w in enumerate(words):
    if '[br]' in w:
        words[i] = w.replace('[br]', '<br />')
```