# python replacing item in list

Tags: python, list, replace

Hi my question relates to a post a long time ago by some user here:

[Find and replace string values in Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136689/find-and-replace-string-values-in-python-list)

For my specific situation. I have a list like this:

```
appl =  ['1', 'a', 'a', '2', 'a']
```

I want to replace only the "a single unknown" instance of "a" with just an empty space(that holds the position of where "a" used to be). I am unsure of how to do it for only one character. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: i Should mention that I need to use an "index" function to first locate the "a" since it is a changing variable. And then I need code that will replace the character.

EDIT2: A lot of people are assuming the index will be 2, but I want to point out that the index of the character is not known. Also "a" will be present in the list approximately ~20 times(will remain a fixed number) but their locations will be changing. I want to replace an "a" based on user input. This is the actual list I am working with:

```
track  [2] =   ["|","@","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"]
```

@ is a charachter, | is a border and " " is an empty space.
A user enters input to choose how much @ moves to the right and a new image is displayed that shows the new location of @ and the old location of @ is replaced with a space. The length of the list remains constant. This is the context of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use index to achieve this goal, along with a loop.
Here is a little function for it:

```
def replace_element(li, ch, num, repl):
    last_found = 0
    for _ in range(num):
        last_found = li.index(ch, last_found+1)
    li[li.index(ch, last_found)] = repl
```

use:

```
replace_element(appl, 'a', 2, ' ')
```

This method is particularly nice because it throws the following error when the charactor is not in the list:

```
ValueError: 'a' is not in list
```

Comment: This is not right ``appl.index('a', 2)`` means to start at location 2, not find the second occurrence.

Comment: `appl.index('a', 2) means find the second index of a`. Nope, it doesn't. It means that the search starts at character 2.

Comment: @phihag ah sorry brain fart there, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply find the index of the second occurrence by traversing the list and storing the indexes whose elements are `'a'` until you've found two:

```
>>> appl = ['1', 'a', 'a', '2', 'a']
>>> idxs = (i for i,c in enumerate(appl) if c == 'a')
>>> next(idxs)
0
>>> appl[next(idxs)] = ''
>>> appl
['1', 'a', '', '2', 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
appl = ['1', 'a', 'a', '2', 'a']
a_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(appl) if x == 'a']

if len(a_indices) > 1:
    appl[a_indices[1]] = ' '
```

Comment: is this also for just the second occurence?

Answer (score 1):

First, find the first occurrence of the value:

```
>>> appl = ['1', 'a', 'a', '2', 'a']
>>> first = appl.index('a')
>>> first
1
```

To find the second, start at the first location plus one:

```
>>> second = appl.index('a', first+1)
>>> second
2
```

Then set that location to a space like you want:

```
>>> appl[second] = ' '
>>> appl
['1', 'a', ' ', '2', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your list (with `"|"`, `"@"`) is short and `"@"` is always present, just in different locations. In this case you can replace the first occurrence of `"@"` in the `appl` list in one line:

```
appl[appl.index("@")] = " "
```

If the list is large and the item might not be present:

```
i = next((i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == item), None)
if i is not None:
   lst[i] = replacement
```