# Find and replace with multiple string values in Python List

Tags: python, string, list

So very much like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136689/find-and-replace-string-values-in-python-list) except that I would like to replace any part of `words` that matches with anything in `error_list` with `''`.

```
error_list = ['[br]', '[ex]', 'Something']
words = ['how', 'much[ex]', 'is[br]', 'the', 'fish[br]', 'noSomething', 'really']
```

The desired output would be

```
 words = ['how', 'much', 'is', 'the', 'fish', 'no', 'really']
```

My vain attempt was,

```
words = [w.replace(error_list , '') for w in word]
```

EDIT: Maybe I should also say that I have done this with loops but was looking for a more pythonic way.

Comment: Googling your question's exact title produced some good information (the linked target was the first hit).

Comment: The answer on "Python replace multiple strings" would certainly work but it is maybe a little too powerful. Ultimately, I would have to create a dict  with my list as the keys and with `""` as the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error_list = ['[br]', '[ex]', 'Something']
words = ['how', 'much[ex]', 'is[br]', 'the', 'fish[br]', 'noSomething', 'really']   

for j in error_list:
    for index, i in enumerate(words):
            if(j in i):
                    i1=i.replace(j,"")
                    words[index]= i1
```

**output**

```
['how', 'much', 'is', 'the', 'fish', 'no', 'really']
```

**[See it in action](https://repl.it/BXab)**

Comment: This was similar to my original approach with loops so it should work nicely. +1

Comment: @josh We can Skip `if-case` !! and welcome for any new approaches..