# How do I find letters in words that are part of a string and remove them? (List comprehensions with if statements)

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to remove vowels from a string. Specifically, remove vowels from words that have more than 4 letters.

Here's my thought process:

(1) First, split the string into an array.

(2) Then, loop through the array and identify words that are more than 4 letters.

(3) Third, replace vowels with "".

(4) Lastly, join the array back into a string.

Problem: I don't think the code is looping through the array.
Can anyone find a solution?

```
def abbreviate_sentence(sent):

    split_string = sent.split()
    for word in split_string:
        if len(word) > 4:
            abbrev = word.replace("a", "").replace("e", "").replace("i", "").replace("o", "").replace("u", "")
            sentence = " ".join(abbrev)
            return sentence


print(abbreviate_sentence("follow the yellow brick road"))      # => "fllw the yllw brck road"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace string values in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136689/find-and-replace-string-values-in-list)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the "abbrev = words.replace..." line was incomplete.

I changed it to:

```
abbrev = [words.replace("a", "").replace("e", "").replace("i", "").replace("o", "").replace("u", "") if len(words) > 4 else words for words in split_string]
```

I found the part of the solution here: [Find and replace string values in list.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136689/find-and-replace-string-values-in-list)

It is called a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

I also found [List Comprehension with If Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474933/list-comprehension-with-if-statement/15474969)

The new lines of code look like:

```
def abbreviate_sentence(sent):

    split_string = sent.split()
    for words in split_string:
        abbrev = [words.replace("a", "").replace("e", "").replace("i", "").replace("o", "").replace("u", "")
                        if len(words) > 4 else words for words in split_string]
        sentence = " ".join(abbrev)
        return sentence


print(abbreviate_sentence("follow the yellow brick road"))      # => "fllw the yllw brck road"
```