# Python Find and replace multiple strigs with a single string in a list

Tags: python, string, list

I want to replace multiple strings with a single string in a list. Reference: [Find and replace string values in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136689/find-and-replace-string-values-in-list)

```
cols = ['M23group','M23met_event', 'M23mode', 'M23validation_1min', 'M23validation_2min', 'M23voltage',
 'M24AmbientAir_Av', 'M24Efficiency', 'M24FF', 'M24Impp', 'M24Isc',]
  cols = [w.replace('M23'|'M24', 'M') for w in cols]
```

Present output:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string replace() method takes 1 source and 1 destination, try this:

```
w.replace("M23", 'M').replace("M24", 'M')
```

Line should be like below:

```
cols = [w.replace("M23", 'M').replace("M24", 'M') for w in cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

cols input - 
['M23group', 'M23met_event', 'M23mode', 'M23validation_1min', 'M23validation_2min', 'M23voltage', 'M24AmbientAir_Av', 'M24Efficiency', 'M24FF', 'M24Impp', 'M24Isc']

```
cols = [w.replace('M23', 'M').replace('M24', 'M') for w in cols]
```

cols output - 
['Mgroup', 'Mmet_event', 'Mmode', 'Mvalidation_1min', 'Mvalidation_2min', 'Mvoltage', 'MAmbientAir_Av', 'MEfficiency', 'MFF', 'MImpp', 'MIsc']