# How to find text between `*~`?

Tags: python, regex

There are lots of special characters in these text file I get and I am trying to find and replace them with other strings. For example:

```py
s = "BRAND~*HP*5250*RAM128*GPUAMD7990*~"

df = re.findall('BRAND~*(.+?)*~', s)

print(df)
```

The result yield `['*']`

I want the result to be `HP*5250*RAM128*GPUAMD7990`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: how is the `*` jumping after `128`?

Comment: `findall` returns a `list` not a `string`... would't be easier to use string methods  `s.removeprefix("BRAND~*").removesuffix("*~")` or `re.sub`?

Comment: with a __lookahead assertion__ `r'~\*(.+)(?=\*~)'`

Answer (score 2):

Escape the `*` in the pattern:

```
s = "BRAND~*HP*5250*RAM128*GPUAMD7990*~"

out = re.findall('BRAND~\*(.+?)\*~', s)
```

Output:

```
['HP*5250*RAM128*GPUAMD7990']
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the '*'s:

```
df = re.findall('BRAND~\*(.+?)\*~', str)
```

Comment: Same thing for `~` or others.

Comment: `~` has no special meaning in regular expressions and doesn't need escaping

Comment: You are right! my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You want to

1. match the `*` asterisk as a normal 'character, and
2. strip the remaining `*`

PS: *I see your question has been edited. You may discard the 'strip' part. It seems you did not need that anymore.*

[**match / find**]

```py
import re

## find match based on regex pattern
df = re.findall('BRAND~\*(.+?)\*~', str)
df
```

[out]
`['HP*5250*RAM128*GPUAMD7990']`

[**strip / remove**]

```py
r = re.compile('(\*)')
[r.sub('', w) for w in df]
```

out
`['HP5250RAM128GPUAMD7990']`

---

PS: Others might assist with a more python code!

PS: You may want to take note of [Find and replace string values in list [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136689/find-and-replace-string-values-in-list)

Comment: Hi semmyk-research. Your post is right on. Just a small warning. Forcing a match between delimiters using `.+?` could consume a delimiter if the content were empty. The adverse affect is to go to the next valid delimiter it finds.

Comment: @sln Thanks for pointing this out. #Appreciated. Some of these things, one gets to overlook easily at ones detriment (down the line).
Apparently, `.+` gets even greedy~

Comment: Yeah so `.*?` single character checks for the end delimiter might be better always in this cases.

Answer (score 1):

A pair of lookarounds will get the center.

```
(?<=BRAND~\*).*?(?=\*~)
```

https://regex101.com/r/zdkmYD/1

But to replace specific characters within that match requires a callback function.